# Is HarmonyOS on topic?

Tags: discussion, support

[HarmonyOS is an Android alternative for phones, watches, and IoT devices](https://www.engadget.com/2019-08-09-huawei-harmony-os-hongmeng-android.html)

> Huawei's long-rumored Android alternative, Hongmeng, is finally official. At today's Huawei Developer Conference, the company's Consumer Business Group CEO Richard Yu surprised the audience by unveiling "HarmonyOS," which he says is faster and safer than Android. That said, the software is primarily aimed at IoT products (such as smart displays, wearables, smart speakers and in-car devices) instead of smartphones. Yu says that when Huawei can no longer access Google's Android ecosystem, the company can deploy HarmonyOS "at any time." Until then, Huawei will continue to support Android.

It replaces Android on some devices. Will this be on topic on the site?

Answer (score 1):

Harmony OS is said to be a *fork*  of Android not withstanding contrary claims by Huawei.

**Sources**

- [Huawei will show off HarmonyOS, its clone of Android, on June 2](https://9to5google.com/2021/05/25/huawei-harmonyos-reveal-date/amp/?__twitter_impression=true)
- [Huawei’s HarmonyOS: “Fake it till you make it” meets OS development](https://arstechnica.com/gadgets/2021/02/harmonyos-hands-on-huaweis-android-killer-is-just-android/)

So, IMO, it should be very much on topic on this site, unless proved that it's independent of Android.

PS: If this position is agreeable to the community, a separate tag needs to be created.

Comment: I don't see how it can be a fork of android, it's a microkernel. Unless they're totally lying.

Comment: That's what's been mentioned in the linked articles and my answer is based on that (BTW arstechnica is quite reputed and  well spoken of)

Comment: @ISupportTheBoycott Wikipedia (through Android Authority and The Verge) mentioned that it can install APK and run Android app, and has built-in Android 10's easter egg.